# Vectorize loop that involves matrix value updates in MATLAB

Tags: performance, matlab, for-loop, dependencies, vectorization

The `for` loop is as follows:

```
N = 2;T = 3;
Trials = rand(N,T);
for i=1:N
    for j=1:T
        AverageValue = mean2(Trials);
        Trials(i,j) = Trials(i,j) - AverageValue;
    end
end
```

The difficulty is that `AverageValue` changes its value according to each updated `Trials`.

===========================================

**Updated version with 'mean2' replaced by 'trapz'**:

```
N=4;T=5;
Trials=rand(N,T);
for i=1:N
    for j=1:T
        IntValue=trapz(trapz(Trials(1:3,2:5)));
        Trials(i,j)=Trials(i,j)+IntValue;
    end
end
```

Please help, thank you!

Comment: Thank yuk for answer! But 'mean2' is exactly what I want. And this is why 'Trials' matrix changes after each iteration ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will produce the same output as your example in the post:

```
 n = numel(Trials);
 Trials = Trials - mean2(Trials)*reshape(((n-1)/n).^(0:n-1), T, N)';
```

**Explanation**: By observing the pattern created by your recursive subtraction of the mean you have for each current mean `m` a relationship of the form:

```
 m(k) = m(k-1) - m(k-1)/n = ((n-1)/n)*m(k-1); % symbolic
```

Thus you can directly subtract a matrix from your original with the embedded recursion, i.e.

```
[m(1) m(2) m(3);
 m(4) m(5) m(6)];
```

where each `m` is replaced analytically using the acummulation of previous values according to the rule `m(k)= (((n-1)/n)^(k-1)*)m(1);`, where `m(1)` is the average of the original matrix.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It works. I would like to know if this principle can be applied for other function than mean2, e.g., an integral function of 'Trials'?

Comment: @huynhkhactuan the recursion principle will work,as long as you can formulate/write your function as such.

Comment: Dear gevang, I have updated the code by replacing 'mean2' by 'trapz'. I understand well the principle, but I can't build a recursive relation for the updated version. Could you please help me to vectorize it. Thank you so much.